# ggplot does not work if it is inside a for loop although it works outside of it

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm using a simple ggplot function which works fine outside a loop but not inside even if the iterative value does not interfere with the ggplot function. Why is it so ?

Here is my code

```
x=1:7
y=1:7
df = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
```

It works ! But if the ggplot is inside a for loop ...

```
for (i in 1:5) {
   ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
}
```

it doesn't work anymore, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

When in a `for` loop, you have to explicitly `print` your resulting `ggplot` object :

```
for (i in 1:5) { 
    print(ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()) 
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is the case?

Comment: @SydKerckhove In case you are still interested, here is an excellent article about ggplot: http://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/Beneath-the-canvas/

Comment: How do you use this with ggsave?

Comment: @John `myPlot = ggplot()..... ` then `ggsave("filename", plot = myPlot)`

Comment: This is probably off topic, but I'm not sure there is any value in posting about my confusion independently: The suggested `print(ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point())` works, but `ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point() %>% print()` does not. However, `(ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()) %>% print()` does work. This is probably related to the "not a pipe" nature of the ggplot `+` described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166708/plus-sign-between-ggplot2-and-other-function-r

Comment: Disclaimer, I am a total noob. Can you explain i in 1:5 please?

Comment: @yaynikkiprograms, perhaps too late, but ... type in [`?:`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Colon.html), and see that it is a shortcut for sequences.

Comment: I have also found the need to use `print()` when exporting from within a `for` loop...e.g. `jpeg(...) print( ggplot(...) ) dev.off()`

Comment: I found had to use print(ggdraw(...)) as well to get  to work inside a loop