# Strange issue with ggplot inside a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to plot couple of graphs (named p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6) with ggplot inside a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:6){
assign(paste0("p",i), ggplot(TS, aes(Timestamp,TS[,i+1])) +
geom_line() +
scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("5 day")) +
theme_few())
}

p<-arrangeGrob(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6)
ggsave("~/Desktop/TS.png",p)
```

However, all graphs come out identical to the last one. i.e., p1 = p2 = p3 = p4 = p5 = p6! This is not possible since the variable values used to plot them are very different. This is very strange and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. When I don't use a for loop and store the plots in p1,...p6 manually, i.e.,

```
assign(paste0("p",1), ggplot(TS, aes(Timestamp,TS[,2])) +
geom_line() +
scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("5 day")) +
theme_few())
   .
   .
   .
assign(paste0("p",6), ggplot(TS, aes(Timestamp,TS[,7])) +
geom_line() +
scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("5 day")) +
theme_few())
```

everything is fine.

I also tried

```
p <- list()
for(i in 1:6){
p[[i]] <- ggplot(TS, aes(Timestamp,TS[,i+1])) +
geom_line() +
scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("5 day")) +
theme_few()
}
do.call(grid.arrange,p)
```

But the same problem happened.

I found another thread (here:[ggplot does not work if it is inside a for loop although it works outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/r-ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of)) with seemingly a similar problem but that issue was resolved using "print". Here in my case I am assigning each plot to the corresponding "p"i so it should work as well.

Comment: Use the column names instead of the indices. Or use `lapply` instead.

Comment: How can I use column names? they are supposed to change inside the for-loop.

Comment: `for (i in colnames(TS)[2:7])` ... `aes_string(x="Timestamp", y=i)` ...

Comment: I don't think the output of arrangeGrob is a ggplot object. You can save using `pdf(filename.pdf); arrangeGrob(p1,p2,...etc); dev.off` though.

Comment: @jraab No I was trying to save it with ggsave. It is working now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments. The issue was resolved as follows:

```
for (i in colnames(TS)[2:6]) {
assign(paste0("p",i),ggplot(TS, aes_string(x="Timestamp", y=i)) +
       geom_line() +
       scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("5 day")) +
       theme_few())
}

p<-arrangeGrob(pT1,pT2,pT3,pT4,pT5,pT6)
ggsave("~/Desktop//TS.png",p)
```