# Plus sign between ggplot2 and other function (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, operators

I'm trying to get this example:

> ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point()

Can somebody explain me what's going on here between these 2 functions?

Does ggplot2 overload "plus" operator? What is the result of summarizing these 2, and what is it assigned to? Is it R-specific feature, or ggplot2-specific? Is it kind of pipe?

Comment: It's not easy to find, but `help("+.gg")` has the information you want.  I found out that `+.gg` exists by using `methods("+")` with ggplot2 loaded.

Comment: Yes and no; it's effectively a pipe (Hadley discovered/coauthored magrittr after ggplot2, and has said it's too late to change ggplot now), but it's actually adding to a ggplot object, which is not plotted until the call is complete. So yes, you can think of it as passing the `data` parameter between functions, but it's more useful to think of it as...additive. Wrap a plot in `ggplot_build` to get an idea of what the objects are inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function definition that @Richard Scriven refers to in comment is defined in [`plot-construction.r`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/plot-construction.r), which might make it clearer. You'll need to go through the source to see exactly what those two (unexported) functions do (whether the LHS of the call is a `theme` or a `ggplot` object) but the names should give you a pretty good idea. The return value is `e1` modified by "adding" `e2`.

```
"+.gg" <- function(e1, e2) {
  # Get the name of what was passed in as e2, and pass along so that it
  # can be displayed in error messages
  e2name <- deparse(substitute(e2))

  if      (is.theme(e1))  add_theme(e1, e2, e2name)
  else if (is.ggplot(e1)) add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
}
```

So, yes, `+` is overloaded for objects inheriting class `gg` (all `ggplot2` objects).

I think 'pipe' (@alistaire's comment) is a misleading analogy; this is very much in the style of the standard Ops group generic.