# Warning messages preventing for loop from finishing and plots generating

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, try-catch, warnings

I am ultimately trying to create a PDF that contains several plots using a for loop. When I run the plots individually I get a warning message, but the plot generates. However, when I run the plots in a `for` loop, the plots do not generate. I think this is because the for loop stops after the first warning message appears.

Here is the code for a singular plot which has a warning message but generates a plot:

```
ggplot(raw[raw$Sector==sectorname,],aes(x=SEP_Score)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  facet_grid(~LabelYear_AUTO) + 
  stat_bin(breaks=rng) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Count")
```

When I run this code, a plot generates but I receive the following warning:

```
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

Again, I'm fine with the binwidth. I don't want to change anything.

Now when I modify the code slightly so that multiple plots would generate no plots show in my viewer. Here is the code I've used.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(table(raw$Sector))){

 sectorname=rownames(table(raw$Sector))[i]

 ggplot(raw[raw$Sector==sectorname,],aes(x=SEP_Score)) + 
   geom_histogram() + 
   facet_grid(~LabelYear_AUTO) + 
   stat_bin(breaks=rng) + 
   scale_y_continuous(name = "Count"))
}
```

How do I tell R to ignore all warning messages and just run the task I want it to?

I've tried the following code by wrapping `try` around the problematic text to no avail.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(table(raw$Sector))){

 sectorname=rownames(table(raw$Sector))[i]
  try(ggplot(raw[raw$Sector==sectorname,],aes(x=SEP_Score)) + 
        geom_histogram() +
        facet_grid(~LabelYear_AUTO) +   
        stat_bin(breaks=rng) + 
        scale_y_continuous(name = "Count")
      )
    }
```

Comment: What you're receiving is not a warning, but a message. Try explicitly adding a `print()` statement around your ggplot code.

Comment: `?suppressMessages()`

Comment: Both print() and suppressMessages() generate the same message/warning

Comment: If you just want to suppress the message, but keep the bins the same, just do `geom_histogram(bins = 30)`.

Comment: Adding geom_histogram(bins = 30) suppressed the message. However, multiple plots are still not generating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: ggplot does not work if it is inside a for loop although it works outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/r-ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of)

Comment: It works for me when the plot is wrapped in print(). Do you have any sample data?