# Using "eval" within a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, eval, assign

I'd like to dynamically assign a plot to a variable name, and then call that variable latter on within a loop. While using "eval" outside of a loop seems to work just fine, placing it within a loop stops it from working as expected.

```
#Sample data frame
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y<-c(5,4,3,2,1)
y2<-c(1,2,3,4,5)


DF<-data.frame(x,y,y2)


#Using ggplot for p and p2
p<-ggplot(DF, aes(x=x, y=y))+
            geom_point()
p2<-ggplot(DF, aes(x=x, y=y2))+
  geom_point()

#Assign p and p2 to string "Plot1" and "Plot2"
assign(paste0("Plot",1), p )
assign(paste0("Plot",2), p2 )


#Create a list to hold all plot names
plotlist<-c("Plot1", "Plot2")




#Print plots to a pdf
pdf(paste0("Plot", "_Test.pdf"), height =8, width=16)

for(i in seq(1,length(plotlist))){
  plotname<-plotlist[i]
  plotter<-eval(parse(text=plotname))
  plotter
  print(plotname)

}

dev.off()
```

Note that the above does not work. But if I am to run the same eval statements outside of the loop, AKA:

```
  i=1
  plotname<-plotlist[i]
  plotter<-eval(parse(text=plotname))
  plotter
```

The plot is created as expected. Is there a way to call "eval" within a loop? And what about being in a loop causes eval statement to work differently?

Note, by removing the for loop, it saves the (first) pdf as expected:

```
pdf(paste0("Plot", "_Test.pdf"), height =8, width=16)

#for(i in seq(1,length(plotlist))){
  plotname<-plotlist[i]
  plotter<-eval(parse(text=plotname))
  plotter
  print(plotname)

#}

dev.off()
```

Comment: It should be `print(plotter)`, not `print(plotname)` to actually print the plot to the output device rather than just the name (or you can print both). But using `assign` and `eval` isn't really a good pattern in R. You should be storing related items in list and applying functions over those lists rather than looping. It makes everything so much easier.

Comment: The "print" statement was to print out the "plotname" to ensure I was evaluating the correct statement

Comment: The plot should print from the "plotter" line above the print statement

Comment: Well, you need to explicitly `print()` ggplot objects inside of a loop, otherwise they will not render like base graphics plots will. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/r-ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of for example.

Comment: Adding "print(plotter)" does not fix the issue

Comment: If I add `print(plotter)` just before `print(plotname)` and run your first code chunk, i get a pdf with both plots. Is there something else you were trying to fix?

Comment: I think MrFlick was correct, that I need to explicitly call "print" for a ggplot object. I assumed it was a problem with the "eval" aspect, but it was an issue with how I was using ggplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more R-like way to do this avoiding the assign/eval would be

```
DF <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  y = c(5,4,3,2,1),
  y2 = c(1,2,3,4,5))

plotlist <- list(
  Plot1 = ggplot(DF, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point(),  
  Plot2 = ggplot(DF, aes(x=x, y=y2)) +
    geom_point()
)

pdf(paste0("Plot", "_Test.pdf"), height =8, width=16)
lapply(plotlist, print)
dev.off()
```

All your plots here are easily stored in a list that we can just `lapply()` over when needed.

The main problem is that ggplot objects won't render until they are `print()`ed. When you work in the console, by default the result of the last expression is `print()`ed. But when you run a loop, that default `print()`ing doesn't happen. That's described in this previous question: [R: ggplot does not work if it is inside a for loop although it works outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/r-ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of)