# An issue with tiff and ggplot R functions inside for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: broken image[![][1]]]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l44Qr.png)

I was not able to get a batch of images with `tiff()` `R` function inside `for` loop.

I have `x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)` platform with installed `Windows 8.1` and `RStudio  Version 1.0.143` with `R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) -- "Planting of a Tree"`. I tried to obtaine a batch of `tiff` images by putting my code inside the `for` loop. Unfortunately that resulted in the numerous broken files (in attachment). But if i type exactly the same code in the RStudio console i got normal (valid) image.

```
#Fragment of the script
    for (i in 1:nrow(BH))
    {
    ...
    tiff( paste(pos$rs[1],"tiff",sep = '.'))
    ggplot(df_g_,aes(x=factor(g),fill=factor(O)))+geom_bar(stat="count")+xlab("")+labs(fill='')
    dev.off()
    }

#If i perform the following code in console after script execution i got a valid image

    tiff( paste(pos$rs[1],"tiff",sep = '.'))
    ggplot(df_g_,aes(x=factor(g),fill=factor(O)))+geom_bar(stat="count")+xlab("")+labs(fill='')
    dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to envelop `ggplot`function by base `print` function in the loop:

```
print(ggplot(df_g_,aes(x=factor(g),fill=factor(O)))+geom_bar(stat="count")+xlab("")+labs(fill=''))
```

So, i've used the solution from the other post:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/r-ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of)