# ggplot2 does not work in a function, but in outside it works

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to run `ggplot2` but it does not work in the following function `foo()`. Why?

```
foo <- function(aaa=TRUE) {

  df<-data.frame(x=c(10,100,1000,10,100,1000),
                 y=c(1100,220000,33000000,1300,240000,36000000),
                 group=c("1","1","1","2","2","2")
  )



if (aaa==TRUE) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = group)) +
    ggplot2::geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.2)) +           # Dodge lines by 0.2
    ggplot2::geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 4)+  # Dodge points by 0.2
    ggplot2::scale_y_log10()+
    ggplot2::scale_x_log10()
}

  if (aaa==FALSE) {
    ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = group)) +
      ggplot2::geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.2)) +           # Dodge lines by 0.2
      ggplot2::geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 4)+  # Dodge points by 0.2
      ggplot2::scale_y_log10()
      # ggplot2::scale_x_log10()
  }

}
```

I cannot understand  why    `foo(T)` does not work but `foo(F)` work.

Note that foo(T) runs the following codes, and it works outside the function `foo`.

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(10,100,1000,10,100,1000),
               y=c(1100,220000,33000000,1300,240000,36000000),
               group=c("1","1","1","2","2","2")
)

ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = group)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.2)) +           # Dodge lines by 0.2
  ggplot2::geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 4)+  # Dodge points by 0.2
  ggplot2::scale_y_log10()+
  ggplot2::scale_x_log10()
```

---

**Edit for the answer** of `@Ronak Shah`

if we use `if` statement successively, then it lost the object as the following code.

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(10,100,1000,10,100,1000),
               y=c(1100,220000,33000000,1300,240000,36000000),
               group=c("1","1","1","2","2","2")
)

aaa<-TRUE

if (aaa==TRUE) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = group)) +
    ggplot2::geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.2)) +           # Dodge lines by 0.2
    ggplot2::geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 4)+  # Dodge points by 0.2
    ggplot2::scale_y_log10()+
    ggplot2::scale_x_log10()
}

.Last.value

if (aaa==FALSE) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = group)) +
    ggplot2::geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.2)) +           # Dodge lines by 0.2
    ggplot2::geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 4)+  # Dodge points by 0.2
    ggplot2::scale_y_log10()
  # ggplot2::scale_x_log10()
}

.Last.value
```

---

**Edit for the answer** of @Jules Stuifbergen

Using `return()`

```
# General print of log scale

foo <- function(aaa=TRUE) {

  df<-data.frame(x=c(10,100,1000,10,100,1000),
                 y=c(1100,220000,33000000,1300,240000,36000000),
                 group=c("1","1","1","2","2","2")
  )



if (aaa==TRUE) {
 return( ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = group)) +
    ggplot2::geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.2)) +           # Dodge lines by 0.2
    ggplot2::geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 4)+  # Dodge points by 0.2
    ggplot2::scale_y_log10()+
    ggplot2::scale_x_log10()
 )

}

  if (aaa==FALSE) {
    ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = group)) +
      ggplot2::geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.2)) +           # Dodge lines by 0.2
      ggplot2::geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 4)+  # Dodge points by 0.2
      ggplot2::scale_y_log10()
      # ggplot2::scale_x_log10()

  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not work?

Comment: Plot is  not displayed when I execute `foo(T)`.

Comment: Use print() around the ggplot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of-it

Comment: Thanks @user2974951. Using `print()`, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function returns the object which is present in the last line of the function unless you have mentioned `return` explicitly. In your function you have two `if` condition. When `aaa` is `TRUE` it will go inside the `if` function and then check for `if (aaa==FALSE)` which is the next statement hence, the original `ggplot` object is lost when `aaa` is `TRUE`

Your function would work simply by replacing second `if` with only `else`. Also note that if your condition is already logical you don't need to check `if(aaa==TRUE)`, only `if (aaa)` would work.

So change the function to

```
foo <- function(aaa=TRUE) {

  df<-data.frame(x=c(10,100,1000,10,100,1000),
             y=c(1100,220000,33000000,1300,240000,36000000),
             group=c("1","1","1","2","2","2"))

  if (aaa) {
    ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = group)) +
      ggplot2::geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.2)) +         
      ggplot2::geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 4)+
      ggplot2::scale_y_log10()+
      ggplot2::scale_x_log10()
  }
  else {
     ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, shape = group)) +
      ggplot2::geom_line(position = position_dodge(0.2)) +        
      ggplot2::geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 4) +
      ggplot2::scale_y_log10()  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I confirmed your answer by using `.Last.value` as the above. Your Great :-D

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment, so here's an answer:

As said, a function returns what's on the last line, so the last line is a plot, only in the FALSE condition.

So: Use `return()` around the ggplot calls in both loops, and it works.

If you use `print()` then the function will *always* print the plot, and will return unexpected results:

```
p <- foo(FALSE)     # prints the plot
p + theme_minimal() # works

p <- foo(TRUE)     # prints the plot
p + theme_minmal() # doesnt work
```

Comment: Thank you!! So, I've never thought that  " the last line is a plot"". Thank you.