# How to for loop in R over a variable

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

My question is about using a for loop to repeat data analysis based on a categorial variable.

Using the built in `Iris` data set how would I run a for loop on the code below so it first produces this chart for just setosa and then versicolor and then virginica without me having to manually change/set the species?

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
```

I'm just starting out and have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: Do you need to do it in a loop? Could you use `ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Species)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `print()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of-it)

```
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)

species <- iris |> distinct(Species) |> unlist()

for(i in species) {
  p <- iris |> 
    filter(Species == i) |> 
    ggplot() + 
      geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
      ggtitle(i)
  print(p)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop as u/DanY posted; however, it's harder to store and retrieve plots in a universal way with that structure.  Running the loop code makes it difficult to retrieve any one particular plot - you would only see the last plot in the output window and have to go "back" to see the others.  I would suggest using a list structure instead to allow you to retrieve any one of the individual plots in subsequent functions.
For this, you can use `lapply()` rather than `for(...) { ... }`.

Here's an example which uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

unique_species <- unique(iris$Species)

myPlots <- lapply(unique_species, function(x) {
  ggplot(
    data = iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == x),
    mapping = aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title=paste("Plot of ", x))
})
```

You then have the plots stored within `myPlots`.  You can access each plot via `myPlots[1]`, `myPlots[2]` or `myPlots[3]`... or you can plot them all together via `patchwork` or another similar package.  Here's one way using `cowplot`:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = myPlots, nrow=1)
```

[image]